# Looping through lines in a file in bash, without using stdin

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops

I am foxed by the following situation.

I have a file list.txt that I want to run through line by line, in a loop, in bash. A typical line in list.txt has spaces in. The problem is that the loop contains a "read" command. I want to write this loop in bash rather than something like perl. I can't do it :-(

Here's how I would usually write a loop to read from a file line by line:

```
while read p; do
  echo $p
  echo "Hit enter for the next one."
  read x
done < list.txt
```

This doesn't work though, because of course "read x" will be reading from list.txt rather than the keyboard.

And this doesn't work either:

```
for i in `cat list.txt`; do
    echo $i
    echo "Hit enter for the next one."
  read x
done
```

because the lines in list.txt have spaces in.

I have two proposed solutions, both of which stink:

1) I could edit list.txt, and globally replace all spaces with "THERE_SHOULD_BE_A_SPACE_HERE" . I could then use something like sed, within my loop, to replace THERE_SHOULD_BE_A_SPACE_HERE with a space and I'd be all set. I don't like this for the stupid reason that it will fail if any of the lines in list.txt contain the phrase THERE_SHOULD_BE_A_SPACE_HERE (so malicious users can mess me up).

2) I could use the while loop with stdin and then in each loop I could actually launch e.g. a new terminal, which would be unaffected by the goings-on involving stdin in the original shell. I tried this and I did get it to work, but it was ugly: I want to wrap all this up in a shell script and I don't want that shell script to be randomly opening new windows. What would be nice, and what might somehow be the answer to this question, would be if I could figure out how to somehow invoke a new shell in the command and feed commands to it without feeding stdin to it, but I can't get it to work. For example this doesn't work and I don't really know why:

```
while read p; do 
  bash -c "echo $p; echo ""Press enter for the next one.""; read x;"; 
done < list.txt
```

This attempt seems to fail because "read x", despite being in a different shell somehow, is still seemingly reading from list.txt. But I feel like I might be close with this one -- who knows.

Help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must open as a different file descriptor

```
while read p <&3; do
    echo "$p"
    echo 'Hit enter for the next one'
    read x
done 3< list.txt
```

Update: Just ignore the lengthy discussion in the comments below. It has nothing to do with the question or this answer.

Comment: Also, use `IFS='' read -r p <&3` to ensure you get the exact line from the file, without losing leading or trailing whitespace or processing any backslashes as escape characters.

Comment: @chepner: Okay, added `-r`. `IFS` I unset sometimes at the top of my scripts. After all, we're talking shell here. It's never going to be super safe. We must rely on the environment being halfway sane.

Comment: @JoSo, if you say `IFS= read x` you are altering IFS *only* for the duration of the read command. ([reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Command-Expansion))

Comment: AFAIK, modern shells set IFS directly to the default and do not inherit the value from the environment.  You can override the setting of IFS in a single script, you cannot affect other scripts that are executed (but scripts that are read using the `.` command use the prevailing value of IFS).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Try creating a file `test.sh` containing `test="a test with spaces";
set -- $test; echo $#` and call it `IFS=x sh test.sh` and `sh test.sh`

Comment: @glenn jackman: I know. But I've given up trying to create shell scripts 100% to the spec and write more readable ones now instead. Have you tried reading zero bytes into shell variables? Or command substitutions with outputs containing trailing newlines?

Comment: or trying to pass an array *name* into a function and update/access array values?

Comment: You could also write the `read` as `read -u 3` instead of `read <&3` (question being tagged bash).

Comment: @chepner: I have inserted and then removed again the `IFS=`. Decided I should stop to take part in these discussions. The `IFS=`/`-r` thingie should really go as a comment to the OP. After all, maybe leaving `IFS` or not including `-r` is exactly what was wanted.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I think that's pointless. And the `-u` option to bash's `read` is to me a pointless and even contraproductive feature (redundant, forces incompatibilities while obfuscating things, not even saved keystrokes).

Comment: @JoSo that's your point of view that is not necessarily shared by the whole community.

Comment: @JoSo `IFS='' read...` isn't about safety, it just provides a different behavior which the OP may need. I should have been more explicit about that.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably count lines in a file and iterate each of those using eg. sed. It is also possible to read infinitely from *stdin* by changing while condition to: `while true;` and exit reading with *ctrl+c*.

```
line=0 lines=$(sed -n '$=' in.file)
while [ $line -lt $lines ]
do
    let line++
    sed -n "${line}p" in.file
    echo "Hit enter for the next ${line} of ${lines}."
    read -s x
done
```

AWK is also great tool for this. Simple way to iterate through input would be like:

```
awk '{ print  $0; printf "%s", "Hit enter for the next"; getline < "-" }' file
```

Comment: No need to give wrong / complicated answers to a question with an accepted, clear and simple answer...

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can read from stderr, which by default is connected to the tty as well.  The following then also includes a test for that assumption:

```
(
tty -s <& 2|| exit 1
while read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
    echo 'Hit enter'
    read x <& 2
done < file
)
```